# Implementar Nesbox em Blog

Tags: html, blog

Queria usar o emulador de jogos via navegador nesbox em um blog usando um endereço externo.

Segundo o código HTML disponibilizado pelo desenvolvedor o código pega apenas um trecho do endereço. Segue o exemplo de trecho do código do desenvolvedor para anexar o emulador em uma pagina html:

```
var resizeOwnEmulator = function(width, height)
{
    var emulator = $('#emulator');
    emulator.css('width', width);
    emulator.css('height', height);
}

$(function()
{
    function embed()
    {
        var emulator = $('#emulator');
        if(emulator)
        {
            var flashvars = 
            {
                system : 'sega',
                url : '/roms/Flappy Bird (PD) v1.0.gen'
            };
            var params = {};
            var attributes = {};

            params.allowscriptaccess = 'sameDomain';
            params.allowFullScreen = 'true';
            params.allowFullScreenInteractive = 'true';

            swfobject.embedSWF('flash/Nesbox.swf', 'emulator', '640', '480', '11.2.0', 'flash/expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params, attributes);
        }
    }

    embed();
});
```

Esse código é para disponibilizar em um endereço interno, mas por usar um servidor externo eu coloquei o endereço completo (exemplo: 'http://exemplo.com/nome/flash/nesbox.swf') e o emulador até chega a mostrar na pagina, só que as ROM não carregam corretamente, creio eu porque os demais arquivos (snes.swf, por exemplo) que fazem a emulação da plataforma do emulador não sejam reconhecidos na pasta que criei no servidor externo.

Alguém que conheça esse emulador tem alguma idéia do que é possível fazer para rodar o emulador a partir de um endereço externo?